# Android: librealm-jni.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement

Tags: realm

I am getting the following line in logcat when initialising Realm and the same is shown as a Dialog.

[image]

/data/app/com.my.pkgname/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "librealm-jni.so”

What am I doing wrong and why is shown as a dialog??

The following is what I am doing:

1. I have the realm file in raw folder and am copying it into my internal storage using the following method:

copyBundledRealmFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ms), "ms");

```
private boolean copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
   boolean retVal = false;
   try {
     File file = new File(getFilesDir(), outFileName);
     FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     outputStream.close();
     retVal = true;
   } catch {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

2. After copying the realm file from raw folder successfully I am doing the following

   RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new        RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).name("ms").build(); 
       mRealm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);

Exactly after building the realmConfig object, the logcat shows the following warning and the same is shown in a dialog : 
/data/app/com.my.pkgname/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "librealm-jni.so”.

Realm version(s): 0.88.0
Android Studio version: 1.5.1
Android version and device: Android N Developer Preview, Nexus 5X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just fixed this in 0.88.1 that was released today: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md